# useEffect() is not seeing changes in Array object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
    const [entries, setEntries] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let active = true
    if (active) {
      divisions.forEach((division) => {
        let teams = []
        let tempDivision = division
        db.collection(`${division.ref}/teams`).get().then((docs) => {
          docs.forEach((doc, index) => {
            teams.push(doc.data())
          })
          tempDivision['teams'] = teams
        })
        setEntries(oldArray => [...oldArray, tempDivision])
      })
    }
    
    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [divisions]);
```

I'm looking to get setEntries update and re-render the front end. Currently, `entries` is updated by useEffect() but it doesn't not trigger re-render. So in this case, it's only rendering what is in the initializer `useState([])`

**EDIT 1**
This is another way i'm trying to "watch" the array, Entries, so that the state can be re-rendered, but I am still not successful

```
export const TeamsTable = ({event, divisions}) => {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState(divisions)
  useEffect(() => {
    let active = true

    if (active) {
      entries.map((division, index) => {
        let teams = []
        db.collection(`${division.ref}/teams`).get().then((docs) => {
          console.log("Tests")
          docs.forEach((doc, index) => {
            teams.push(doc.data())
          })
          entries[index]['teams'] = teams
        })
      })
      setEntries(entries)
    }
    
    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [entries]);

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      { entries.map((division, index) => {
        return <MUIDataTable
          title={<Typography style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{division.name.toUpperCase()}</Typography>}
          data={division.teams}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
          style={{marginBottom: 15}}
          key={index}
        />
      })}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where are you updating the divisions? You are updating the entries array using setEntries.

Comment: Divisions is only used to do the forEach loop. I need the data from Entries.

Comment: You said, `useEffect() is not seeing changes in Array object`. How are you sure that the useEffect is not seeing the change in array object?

Comment: Well the object is changed at the end of the useEffect(), but useEffect is not re-render the front-end. When doing `console.log(entries)`, it's only showing the data from when it was initialized using useState([]) which in this case, an empty’s  array

Comment: @gmnoob temp is never being used.. its only get initialised with empty array.

Comment: @NileshPatel good call, that was an oldd code, I have made edit

Comment: try removing `[divisions]` from the end of the useEffect()

Comment: @theTradeCoder I tried this and you prob already know that it will gives warning for missing dependency

Comment: @gmnoob will entries hold team list? you fetching all teams data??

Comment: removed including `[]`?

Comment: @theTradeCoder, removing included `[]`results infinite loop. @NileshPetal `entries` will hold division information and the collection of teams participating in this division. `{ teamName, createdBy, teams: [{team1}, team{2}, ...]}`

Comment: Well, in that case, you may need to change codes inside itself, because that dependency  array at the end of the useEffect(), useEffect() will be called only once, so by this way - I think that won't give you any changed/update data unless you refresh the page

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but how do you propose I change the codes inside? @theTradeCoder

Comment: Can you ```console.log``` entries outside of your ```useEffect```? As long as your ```db.collection``` returns some values, it seems that it sets it correctly. Perhaps the values are set, but not rendered correctly? 

Another check I would do, is to make sure you actually get any data back from the ```db.collection```. Cos if that is empty, then your set method would set it to empty array anyway

Comment: @szczocik it's confirmed that I do get data back from `db.collection`. The problem is that it's not re-rendering (some what close to what you said "not rendered correctly")

Comment: I made an edit with a different approach by watching the attach in useEffect(), but I am still not successful at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of looking at the codes and research, I've made the dumbest rookie mistake. The solution to this problem is doing `setEntries` inside the `Promise` method.
Thanks everyone for helping!